# Implementation of **kwargs construct in python

Tags: python

I implemented a class in python which currently inherits from dict, but really, I don't want it to. The main reason for inheriting is so that I can use the **kwargs construct for copying the contents into an argument list.

I presume python does some sort of iteration over the dictionary, but I can't find any documentation.

Is this possible, and, if so, how?

Code sample just to make things clearer:

```
   class MyThing():
       def __init__(self):
            self.dictionary = {}


   thing = MyThing()
   # code that causes thing.dictionary to be populated
   somefunc(**thing)
```

results in this:

```
TypeError: somefunc() argument after ** must be a mapping, not instance
```

Comment: Your question is too vague.  You can iterate over a dictionary with usual things like `for key in dict` or `for key, val in dict.iteritems()`.  What precisely are you trying to do?  What have you tried?

Comment: In other words, you're wanting to be able to do `anyfunc(**myclassinstance)`?

Comment: You can use `**` on any arbitrary argument passing in or out of any callable, it will just try to unpack it in to the local namespace as a `dict`.  Can you provide a code sample so we can see what you actually need?

Comment: I'd bet that `**` uses the `iterator` interface, so defining `__iter__` in `myclass` that returns an object with an `__iter__` that returns `self` and `next` that returns the next element or `StopIteration` should make `**` work with any object you want.

Comment: It looks like you *might* be able to use the abstract base class `Mapping` from the `Collections` module.  However, my knowledge of `abc`s ends there ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went and read the python source, it seems to use the `keys()` and `__getitem__` methods

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def keys(self):
        return self.data.keys()
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

def f(alpha):
    print alpha

f(**A({'alpha': 2}))
```

For the curious, If you use ** on a non-dict, CPython creates a new empty dict, and then calls `dict.update()` to copy your object's keys into the dict.

Its probably to best to implement this as a subclass of `collections.Mapping`

```
class A(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]
```

Due to the inheritance from Mapping, pretty much all dict methods are supported. Given the error message, I think you can argue that this should qualify in all implementations of python.

I've tried PyPy and it accepts the first version.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer for `Cpython`.  It doesn't seem to work in `Jython`.  To get it to work there, I needed to add a `__len__` method.  I don't currently have pypy, so I can't test that one...

Comment: Is the dict unpack mechanism officially exposed as part of the Python spec?  From this answer and mgilson's comment, it seems not... I tried looking around, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: No, it's not, as far as I can tell. Deriving from `dict` or `collections.Mapping` (`collections.abc.Mapping` in Python 3) is safest.